# SVG in list-style-image breaks when adding fill

Tags: theme-development, css, svg

I'm trying to add a custom bullet using CSS `list-style-image`. Here is the attribute:

```
ul {
    list-style-image:url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><svg width='18' height='18' viewBox='0 0 1792 1792' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><path d='m1671,566q0,40 -28,68l-724,724l-136,136q-28,28 -68,28t-68,-28l-136,-136l-362,-362q-28,-28 -28,-68t28,-68l136,-136q28,-28 68,-28t68,28l294,295l656,-657q28,-28 68,-28t68,28l136,136q28,28 28,68z'/></svg>");
}
```

For convenience, this is the SVG file that is embedded in the `list-style-image`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<svg width='18' height='18' viewBox='0 0 1792 1792' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
    <path d='m1671,566q0,40 -28,68l-724,724l-136,136q-28,28 -68,28t-68,-28l-136,-136l-362,-362q-28,-28 -28,-68t28,-68l136,-136q28,-28 68,-28t68,28l294,295l656,-657q28,-28 68,-28t68,28l136,136q28,28 28,68z'/>
</svg>
```

The problem is, when I try to add a `fill` attribute to `<path>`, the whole thing seems to break, as the SVG stop showing up as a bullet (the default `ul` circle bullet shows). I've tried using both `fill='#f00'`, `style='#f00'` and `stroke='#f00'`. All of them breaks the SVG.

Any idea what might be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add fill to a path in a svg that has been converted to base64 like you normally do with inline svgs. Either add the fill before conversion to base64, or add it like this in your current css:

```
fill='%23f00'
```

The above is equivalent to `fill='#f00'`. This goes also for stroke, basically replace `#` with `%23` in base64.

Stroke example: `stroke='%23f00' stroke-width='1'`

So your svg with fill code will be:

```
ul {
    list-style-image:url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><svg width='18' height='18' viewBox='0 0 1792 1792' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><path d='m1671,566q0,40 -28,68l-724,724l-136,136q-28,28 -68,28t-68,-28l-136,-136l-362,-362q-28,-28 -28,-68t28,-68l136,-136q28,-28 68,-28t68,28l294,295l656,-657q28,-28 68,-28t68,28l136,136q28,28 28,68z' fill='%23f00'/></svg>");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a try.